# video upload on tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I was trying to update my own status with only a video, but for some reason, it doesn't work. All of them are .mp4 with less than 1MB.

When I try `upload_result = api.media_upload('file.mp4')` it raises a `TweepError` saying that the file type could not be determined.

When I try `upload_result = api.media_upload(filename = "path of the file", file = "file.mp4")` it triggers [Errno13], saying "Permission Denied"

My IDE is Pycharm Community Edition and I am using python 3.9

If you want the full code, just ask for it in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.9.0/api.html#API.media_upload) you can only upload images

> Use this endpoint to upload images to Twitter.

The upload of video is not currently supported, there is an issue open so it will probably come at some point.

Comment: Thank you, I really hope they fix this soon